# Airflow: is there a way to group operators together outside of a dag?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Is there a way to design a python class that implements a specific data pipeline pattern outside of a dag in order to use this class for all data-pipelines that needs this pattern ?

Example: in order to load data from Google Cloud Storage to Big Query, the process can be to validate ingestion candidate files with data quality tests. Then attempt to load data in a raw table in Big Query then dispatching the file in archive or in a rejected folder depending on loading result.

Doing it one time is easy, what if it needs to be done 1000 times ? i am trying to figure out how to optimize engineering time.

SubDag could be considered but it shows limitations in terms of [performances](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/subdags) and is going to be deprecated [anyway](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12292).

Task groups needs to be part of a dag to be implemented https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1be3ef635fab635f741b775c52e0da7fe0871567/airflow/utils/task_group.py#L35.

One way to achieve the expected behavior might be to generate dags, task groups and tasks from a single python file that leverage dynamic DAGing

Nevertheless, code that is used in this particular file can't be reused somewhere in the code base. It is against DRYness even though DRYness vs understandability is always a tradeoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/break-up-a-big-airflow-dag-into-multiple-files-5262accf6713)

Here is how to solve this question:

You can define a plugin in airflow ./plugins
Lets create a sample taskgroup in ./plugins/test_taskgroup.py

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

def hello_world_py():
        print('Hello World')

def build_taskgroup(dag: DAG) -> TaskGroup:
    
    with TaskGroup(group_id="taskgroup") as taskgroup:
        dummy_task = DummyOperator(
            task_id="dummy_task",
            dag=dag
        )
        python_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id="python_task",
            python_callable=hello_world_py,
            dag=dag
        )

    dummy_task >> python_task
    return taskgroup
```

You can call it in a simple python DAG like this:

```py
from airflow.utils import task_group
from test_plugin import build_taskgroup
from airflow import DAG


with DAG(
    dag_id="modularized_dag",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
) as dag:

    task_group = build_taskgroup(dag)
```

Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this question as well. Airflow 2.0 has released the new feature of Dynamic DAG. Although I'm not sure if it will totally answer your design. It may solve the problem of the single codebase. In my case, I have a function to create a task group with the necessary parameters. Then I iterate to create each DAG with the function to create the task group(s) with different parameters. Here is the overview of my pseudo code:

```
def create_task_group(group_id, a, b, c):
    with TaskGroup(group_id=group_id) as my_task_group:
        # add some tasks
        pass

for x in LIST_OF_THINGS:
    dag_id = f"{x}_workflow"
    schedule_interval = SCHEDULE_INTERVAL[x]

    with DAG(
        dag_id,
        start_date=START_DATE,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    ) as globals()[dag_id]:
        task_group = create_task_group(x, ..., ..., ...)
```

The `LIST_OF_THINGS` here represents a list of different configuration. Each DAG can have different `dag_id`, `schedule_interval`, `start_date`, and so on. You can define your task configuration in some config file, such as JSON or YAML, and parse it as a dictionary as well.

I haven't tried, but technically you maybe you can move the `create_task_group()` into some class and import it too if you will need to reuse the same functionality. Another good thing about task groups is that they can add task dependencies to other tasks or task groups which is very convenient.

I saw a concept of YAML configuration for Airflow DAG using an extra package, but I'm not sure if it's mature yet.

See more information about Dynamic DAG here: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags

Comment: This article answers our question https://towardsdatascience.com/break-up-a-big-airflow-dag-into-multiple-files-5262accf6713

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing @flomalb. Sounds like we are going to a good way, just move the task_group function to somewhere import-able. :)

Answer (score -1):

You should just create your own Operator and then use it inside your DAGs.
Extend BaseOperator and use hooks to BigQuery or whatever you need.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This seems like an alternative solution, 

Nevertheless, a custom operators grouping multiple operators together through hooks lacks visibility in the UI, needs to be built to support idempotency. Moreover you need to maintain this operator with appropriate testing on your own